# Run several GLM models using for loop in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some experiment and I want to run several GLMs model in R using the same variables but different training samples.

Here is some simulated data:

```
resp <- sample(0:1,100,TRUE)
x1 <- c(rep(5,20),rep(0,15), rep(2.5,40),rep(17,25))
x2 <- c(rep(23,10),rep(5,10), rep(15,40),rep(1,25), rep(2, 15))
dat <- data.frame(resp,x1, x2)
```

This is the loop I'm trying to use:

```
n <- 5
for (i in 1:n)
{
  ### Create training and testing data
  ## 80% of the sample size
  # Note that I didn't use seed so that random split is performed every iteration.
  smp_sizelogis <- floor(0.8 * nrow(dat))

  train_indlogis <- sample(seq_len(nrow(dat)), size = smp_sizelogis)

  trainlogis <- dat[train_indlogis, ]
  testlogis  <- dat[-train_indlogis, ]

  InitLOogModel[i] <- glm(resp ~ ., data =trainlogis, family=binomial)
}
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
Error in InitLOogModel[i] <- glm(resp ~ ., data = trainlogis, family = binomial) : 
  object 'InitLOogModel' not found
```

Any thoughts.

Comment: What is `InitLOogModel` supposed to be? A list? Then you need to define it before your loop. `InitLOogModel<-list()` and when you assign to a list you need to use double brackets `InitLOogModel[[i]] <- glm(...)` but this would all be easier with an `lapply()` probably. I'll try to find a good duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. This works

Comment: There are ton of other questions like this, hard for me to pick a favorite. But if you search "regression loop" a bunch of suggestions should come up. The fact that you are using `glm()` isn't really that important in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/) for what you're trying to do. It takes some time to learn, but incorporates many 'best practices'. Once you've learned the basics you'll be able to quickly try models other than a `glm`, and easily compare the models to each other. Here's modified code from your example to get you started.

```
## caret
library(caret)

# your data
resp <- sample(0:1,100,TRUE)
x1 <- c(rep(5,20),rep(0,15), rep(2.5,40),rep(17,25))  
x2 <- c(rep(23,10),rep(5,10), rep(15,40),rep(1,25), rep(2, 15))
dat <- data.frame(resp,x1, x2)

# so caret knows you're trying to do classification, otherwise will give you an error at the train step
dat$resp <- as.factor(dat$resp)

# create a hold-out set to use after your model fitting
# not really necessary for your example, but showing for completeness
train_index <- createDataPartition(dat$resp, p = 0.8,
                                   list = FALSE,
                                   times = 1)

# create your train and test data
train_dat <- dat[train_index, ]
test_dat <- dat[-train_index, ]

# repeated cross validation, repeated 5 times
# this is like your 5 loops, taking 80% of the data each time
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = 5,
                           repeats = 5)

# fit the glm!
glm_fit <- train(resp ~ ., data = train_dat,
                 method = "glm",
                 family = "binomial",
                 trControl = fitControl)

# summary
glm_fit

# best model
glm_fit$finalModel
```